# Failed to export to .xlsx format

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

I tried to export my table to .xlsx format. But it is failed to do that. So far I did this:

```
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'); //should be a correct mimetype
header('Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="contoh-1.xlsx"');
```

Below is the error:
[image]

Here is how I generate the data.
Controller:

```
public function kategori_excel(){
    $paramKategori = $this->input->get('CategoryCode');

    $get_url_kategori = $this->ws_url->GetUrl('CategoryRetrieve?CategoryCode='.$paramKategori);
    $get_json_kategori = json_decode(file_get_contents($get_url_kategori), true);
    $data['itemKategoriToExcel'] = $get_json_kategori['Kategoris'];

    $this->load->view('kategori_excel', $data);
}
```

And here is the view:

```
<table border='1' width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Kode</th>
        <th>Nama</th>
        <th>Definisi</th>
        <th>Unsur Abstrak</th>
        <th>Alias</th>
        <th>Sumber Definisi</th>
        <th>Tanggal</th>
        <th>Tipe Tanggal</th>
        <th>Edisi</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>Other Citation Detail</th>
        <th>Nama Katalog</th>
        <th>Nama Organisasi</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($itemKategoriToExcel as $item): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $item['KodeKategori'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['Nama'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['Definisi'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['UnsurAbstrak'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['Alias'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['SumberDefinisi'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['Tanggal'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['TipeTanggal'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['Edisi'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['Role'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['OtherCitationDetail'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['NamaKatalog'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['NamaOrganisasi'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

How can I fix this thing(s)?

Comment: You need to show how "contoh-1.xlsx" is generated. The contents of that file are the problem - not your headers.

Comment: @DFriend how can I show how "contoh-1.xlsx" is generated? Can you give me example?

Comment: I am asking you how you are creating the file you are trying to export. Are you using a PHP library like PHPExcel or making a csv file or what?

Comment: @DFriend No, I am not using any PHP libraries. I just put my data on table. I updated the code above. You can see it